# Currying a function to get another function: unit -> 'a

Tags: function, f#, currying

Given a higher-order function like the following:

```
let call (f : unit -> 'a) = f()
```

And another function:

```
let incr i = i + 1
```

Is there a way to pass `incr` to `call`, without using a lambda: `(fun () -> incr 1)`?

Obviously, passing `(incr 1)` does not work, as the function is then "fully applied."

**EDIT**

To clarify: I'm wondering if there's a way to curry a function, such that it becomes a function: `unit -> 'a`.

Comment: The lambda is a syntactic shortcut. Not sure sure what you're after here. Btw, is your example oversimplified, or is `fun () -> 2` ok?

Comment: I added some clarification (hopefully) to the question. The question is about a special case of currying.

Comment: Btw, [contrast currying with partial function application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application). What you're doing isn't exactly either, but it's more like partial application than currying.

Comment: I was thinking it's more like partial application, but that's misleading here since that generally means the resulting function accepts a parameter. In this case, since the function's return type is generic, it _could_ return another function, which, I think, fits the definition of currying.

Comment: I agree it is similar enough to cause confusion. I thought it a good idea to make things clear. In other news, congratulations on adding a fourth digit to your rep total!

Comment: Thanks very much. I believe it only took 2 years! Correction: just checked and it took a year and a half. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define such a shortcut yourself:

```
let ap f x = fun () -> f x

call (ap incr 1)
```

If the function you want to transform happens to be a pure function, you can define the constant function instead:

```
let ct x _ = x  (* const is reserved for future use :( *)

call (ct (incr 1))
```

Comment: This is good. I may leave the question open a bit longer. I was mostly just curious if there's some F# syntax I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like an attempt to add laziness to strict F# then some kind of currying.
And in fact there is a built in facility for that in F#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233247.aspx - `lazy` keyword plus awkward `Force`:

Not sure if it's any better than explicit lambda, but still:

```
let incr i = 
    printf "incr is called with %i\n" i
    i+1

let call (f : unit -> 'a) =
    printf "call is called\n"
    f()

let r = call <| (lazy incr 5).Force

printf "%A\n" r
```